# Install a different version of Python

Tags: python, shell

this might be a very simple question but I need your help. I work in a network and I cannot install the programs I want. Anyway, I need to use another version of python, which is installed in the directory /new_version/.
Now, when I type "python" in a shell (I use bash) the command point to the version of python installed in the machine I'm working with. I'd love that when I type "python" this command point to the /new_version/ which I've installed. It would be also better if I can call this "new version" with another command, i.e. python2.

I tried changing the PYTHONPATH in the .bashrc but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
alias newpython="/path/to/your/new_version/python"
```

Add this to your `.bashrc`, you can then start the new python with `newpython` and the standard one with `python`.

Comment: Nope, he didn't. `. It would be also better if I can call this "new version" with another command, i.e. python2.`

Answer (score 2):

Add the line

```
export PATH=/new_version/:$PATH
```

to your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_profile`) file. Then, whenever you run `python`, it will find the new version first in your `PATH`. **Note this is `PATH`, not `PYTHONPATH`.** See the comment by @Aaron.

**Edit:** Only do it this way if you want `python` to point to the new version. Use an `alias` as @cularis suggested if you want to call it something different, or make a symlink with:

```
ln -s /new_version/python /path/to/a/dir/you/add/to/your/path/newpython
```

Comment: I also tried with this but it didn't work. I guess because it looks first at the "python" installed on my machine...

Comment: Yes, but if you do this properly, the new version will be the first `python` it finds. Make sure you use the full path for the new version, and that it's first in your path.

Comment: @Matteo: You have to set **PATH**, not **PYTHONPATH**. The latter just sets the search path for Python modules. The former changes the rules where to find the Python executable (which will know where to find its modules). If in doubt, set *both*.

Answer (score 1):

Install [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). With this you can easily set up different Python versions like that:

```
virtualenv -p /new_version/bin/python
```

Also, virtualenv enables you to easily install other Python packages via `pip install`.

And finally, there's a package called [tox](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox) which can automate testing with different Python versions...